# Get column values of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get the values of cells of a gridview. I am able to access it via label name like this

```
Label cell1 = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("cellLabel"));
```

There are 15-20 columns present, so I want to access the cells via index. I tried it with `e.Row.Cells[2].Text` but I am getting null here.

I cannot access the gridview directly since it is an inner gridview. How can I access the cell value in RowDatabound ?

Sample Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"

    DataKeyNames="CustomerID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">

    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField>

            <ItemTemplate>

                <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />

                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">

                    <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid">

                        <Columns>

                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderId" HeaderText="Order Id" />

                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date" />

                        </Columns>

                    </asp:GridView>

                </asp:Panel>

            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" />

        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />

    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

`gvOrders` is the inner gridview.

Comment: show your .aspx gridView

Comment: best is to use TemplateField instead of BoundField

Comment: You are trying to get the value of parent gridview or nested gridview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it directly from the datasource

```
string str = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "YourColumnName"));
```

To access it via index you can try

```
string str = ((DataBoundLiteralControl)e.Row.Cells[x].Controls[y]).Text;
```

Comment: As I said, I don't want to use name since there are lot, So I want to use the index instead. Is it possible with it ?

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava - But why you wanna avoid names? Don't you think using `index` will make your code error prone?

Comment: No, As I said, there are lots of columns. So I could use for loop for index since I want to use this in some more applications. Using name will be easy to implement in further programs rather than columns.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava:- Updated my code, but using names instead of index will be a better and recommended way.

Answer (score 2):

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string name = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        }
    }
```